# Laravel 4 not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to connect my laravel 4 build to local database with MAMP. I have dones this no problem with many other projects and even other laravel builds on the same machine and mysql server. This one just wont connect.

Here is my db config setup.

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'db_name',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

I set the port to match what I have on my MAMP settings for mysql and user and password are consistent throughout all my projects. Unless there is something else I am not sure about, what  am I missing?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the right database config based on your environment settings?

Comment: Debug return errors? Try use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Unless you change it, MAMP runs MySQL on port 8889. Did you change it to 3306?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my problem. while 127.0.0.1 is the IP address for localhost, Laravel does not seem to like this as a setting.

so instead of:

```
'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
```

I switched it to:

```
'host'      => 'localhost',
```

Connection is now made.